# PlaceAutocomplete inside Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to put PlaceAutocomplete inside Navigation Drawer. Also any project with placeautocomplete api posted on github can be an answer or any source how to make custom nav drawer with placeautocomplete

Here is my code:

Search fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/autocompleteHolder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/customViewPager"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
    android:name="com.x.egerg.fragments.AutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

DrawerLayout

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/searchfraglay"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

AutoComplete fragment

```
class AutoComplete : Fragment(), PlaceSelectionListener {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val autocompleteFragment = fragmentManager!!.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchfraglay, container, false)
    }


override fun onPlaceSelected(p0: Place?) {
    Log.d("OnPlaceSelected", p0?.name.toString())
}

override fun onError(p0: Status?) {
    Log.d("OnPlaceSelected", "error")

}
```

}

inside MainActivity

```
nav_view.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.searchfraglay)

    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.autocompleteHolder, AutoComplete())
    ft.commit()
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.egerg/com.x.egerg.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.x.egerg.fragments.AutoComplete cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment
    at com.x.egerg.fragments.AutoComplete.onCreate(AutoComplete.kt:30)
   xxx
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:267)
    at com.x.egerg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21)
```

Comment: The first argument passed in the `replace()` call is the ID for the `ViewGroup` – e.g., an empty `FrameLayout` – that the `Fragment`'s `View` will be placed into. I don't see anything in your `Activity`'s layout with ID `autocompleteHolder1`. Should it be in `app_bar_main`?

Comment: @MikeM. autocompleteHolder is placed in search layout which is header layout of DrawerLayout. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. It's not always clear what users mean by Navigation Drawer, exactly. Hmm, you might have to set that header programmatically, rather than with the `headerLayout` XML attribute. `NavigationView` takes a bit to get itself setup, and the header `View`s are not going to be available right away, when it's set in the layout. Try removing that `headerLayout`, and using `NavigationView#inflateHeaderView()` instead, before your `FragmentTransaction`. I'm not sure if that'll work, though, as I'm not sure when that header actually gets attached to the `Activity`'s hierarchy.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks but I'm still getting errors, if you can please look at this again. Thread is updated

Comment: I don;t think you can easily put Fragments in Fragments, so not clear what `fragmentManager!!.findFragmentById` is trying to do

Comment: I'm getting a little confused, now. What is `searchfraglay`, exactly? If that's what you have labelled as "Search fragment layout:", why are you trying to set it as a header, _and_ using it as the layout for `AutoComplete`? Also, which `Fragment` is supposed to be in the header, `AutoComplete` or `SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment`?

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry for weird name, searchfraglay is a layout with PlaceAutocomplete inside. I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do. I want to implement PlaceAutocomplete inside NavigationDrawer (something like in AccuWeather app). In header should be PlaceAutocomplete fragment. I tried to put PlaceAutoComplete inside second fragment because I wasn't sure how to handle listener when place is selected when PlaceAutocomplete  is inside Nav Drawer. Without putting autocomplete inside fragment it is working fine but I don't know where to implement onPlaceSelected.

Comment: Solved, it should be implemented in MainActivity. Sorry for wasting your time guys, I didn't check simplest way to do it. Thanks a lot for your time @MikeM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should implement `PlaceSelectionListener` inside MainActivity not in fragment.